# Increase the speed of queries LIKE

Tags: python, sqlite, optimization, sqlalchemy, bigdata

I have a database with a table with at least 500 million records, within a table (urldata) I have the url and description column, I need to do a query by url and return all the lines where there is this url, but there is a problem
let's assume that the database has the following url:

- `https://website.com`
- `www.website.com`
- `sub.website.com`
- `https://website.com/App`

And I do a search for "website.com" I want it to return all occurrences since they are all the same site, but written differently, so I'm using like

This is the database model, I'm using sqlalchemy and sqlite3

```py
class File(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'files'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    size = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)


class UrlData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'urldata'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('files.filename'), nullable=False)
    file = db.relationship('File')
```

Basically the problem is as follows, a simple query in the database, which returns 400 results, takes on average more than 20 seconds, that's a LOT of time, I know that there must be a way to drastically reduce this, to make the query I'm using this:

```py
UrlData.query.filter(UrlData.url.contains(query)).all()
```

My attempt was to index the url column, but this took a lot of time, many hours, and in the end it corrupted the db, besides, this database receives thousands to millions of new rows every day, I think it would be unfeasible to have to index everything

Comment: You should install a full text search extension to SQLite. Otherwise, `contains()` can't take advantage of an index.

Comment: you sure sqlite is right choice for dataset with 500 million rows?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Which one do you think would be a good option? Anyway, since I'm using SQLalchemy, I can swap the database just by changing a row of the.env

Answer (score 0):

> Basically the problem is as follows, a simple query in the database,
> which returns 400 results, takes on average more than 20 seconds,
> that's a LOT of time

This is because your query do full scan on table.
You can speed up only via index for search in strings.

In case of postgress there are trigram gin index

```
create index url_trgm_idx
    on url_data using gin (url gin_trgm_ops);


create index url_trgm_idx
    on <TABLE NAME> using gin (<COLUMN NAME> gin_trgm_ops);
```

this index will speed up queries like

```
select *
from url_data
where url ilike '%tdi%'
```

Or you can use elasticsearch (or other db) with special indexes for text search.

Answer (score 0):

**Add Column(s)**
If you want to stick with SQLite, and you are not happy with the performance of an index on the URL column, you might want to add two additional columns, "TopLevelDomain" and "SecondLevelDomain".  Or of course you could just add one column that would be something like MainDomainName.  You can make these columns shorter and the index should be easier to apply.  You would then need to parse through the data to backfill these columns.  Going forward the application would need to insert and or update the new columns.

Another change is that to benefit from the index, your query would have to filter on the new column(s).

If you're concerned about index size, you might use a partial index: https://sqlite.org/partialindex.html.  Something like :

```
CREATE INDEX ix_url_tld_sld ON 
UrlData(TopLevelDomain,SecondLevelDomain) 
WHERE TopLevelDomain = 'com' and SecondLevelDomain = 'website';
```

Of course, the partial index would only make sense if queries search for a small set of website URLs.

**Full Text Indexing**
Alternatively, without adding additional columns, you could use a SQLite extension for Full Text Indexing:
https://sqlite.org/fts5.html

> FTS5 is an SQLite virtual table module that provides full-text search functionality to database applications. In their most elementary form, full-text search engines allow the user to efficiently search a large collection of documents for the subset that contain one or more instances of a search term. The search functionality provided to world wide web users by Google is, among other things, a full-text search engine, as it allows users to search for all documents on the web that contain, for example, the term "fts5".

**Switch to a different Database**
As soon as I had to mess with a corrupted database, I would be moving to a different database provider.  SQLite provides a guide to help decide if SQLite is the right solution: https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html.  I don't see anything on the page that would indicate that SQLite is the wrong solution.  But Postgres or Microsoft SQL Express are both free and wouldn't have a problem with what you're trying to do.